# Does using React.js limits us on using a node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have been working on React.js for a month now. I have been using Webpack dev server which is a node.js Express server and enables us to render react.js on browser. I want to know whether using React.js will limit us on using only a node.js http server or is there a way we can use a simple http server as well with React.js.

I have also been wondering whether it is useful to use React.js for developing webpages that have mostly pre-fixed contents text fields, data etc. during request/response for any API operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does using React.js limits us on using a node.js server

No. React is predominantly a client side library. It doesn't care how it is served to the client.

In the end you are just writing JavaScript. You can deliver the JavaScript code to the client whichever way you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Generally the answer is no. If you only want to use it as a client-side library, it doesn't matter what the web server is. But actually, react components can also be rendered on server side so you can develop universal/isomorphic apps. In that case you will need a node.js server.
Take a look at [this universal example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example).

Answer (score 0):

we are using php+yii2+react +redux+es6 without node.js server, but ngnix. At the end it is just javascript, so that we use gulp + babelify to translate es6 to es5 and then php yii2 application renders basic container to which react application renders himself.

Node.js is one of the options, you can use wathever server you want, just need something like gulp or webpack to compile your js and all dependencies to the ready to use standalone js.